# How can i build a web service which loads users daily listening history from spotify and presents interesting analytics?

Tags: architecture, airflow, system, spotify, scalability

I have this project idea which involves using the spotify API to load users daily listening history and presenting a weekly wrapped to the user by mail, I need some advice on the architecture. My plan is to use Airflow for running daily tasks and loading the data to postgres and then running a weekly task to generate wrapped. This works for a single user , but how can make it scalable , or is their another way to build this service that i am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets assume you have a list of users, and you want to fetch their data from spotify API.

> This works for a single user , but how can make it scalable

By scalable, I understand that you want to fetch the data efficiently, and here are some options:

- Load the users data in a loop user after user: slow method if you have a big number of users -> not scalable but easy
- Create a kubernetes pod from airflow which use multiprocessing to process data in parallel -> scalable but difficult
- Create as spark job which query the API in parallel and run it from Airflow -> very scalable and not difficult
- Use [Dynamic Task Mapping](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/2.3.0/concepts/dynamic-task-mapping.html) to map each user in a separate Airflow task to fetch and process its data -> scalable as much as your Airflow is scalable and easy

Whatever the method you choose, you can store the data in a remote storage, then process them in one scalable task (spark/trino for ex) to create reports and send them in a third task.